# Adjacent JTextFields in the same JPanel Java Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jtextfield

I'm trying to place two JTextFields horizontally in the same JPanel.

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField tickerField = new JTextField();
        JTextField shareField = new JTextField();

        panel.add(tickerField, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(shareField, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(250, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

For some reason, the panel doesn't divide evenly between the west side and east side, with the tickerfield on the west side taking up 99% the width of the panel, while the sharefield on the east side is barely visible. Is there anyway to place them so their size is evenly distributed across the JPanel?

Comment: Yes.  Specify the width of each `JTextField` and pack the `JFrame` instead of setting the size.

Comment: *tickerfield on the west side taking up 99% the width of the panel...*. I don't see that. Both text fields are barely visible because the default width is 0. When you create the text fields you use code like `new JTextField(10)` so the text field can calculate its preferred width. The frame pack() method will then make sure each component is displayed at its preferred size.